# Is plumbr secure?

Tags: r, plumber

The way I understand it is that [plumbr](https://www.rplumber.io) allows you to turn any R script into an API end point. You can send requests to the API end point and it will return the output that you define in the R script.

Let's assume that I host the script in a Docker instance and that the machine sending the api request has an ssh tunnel to the machine.

Let's say I send this dataframe as a response to an api request in plumbr.

```
my_data <- data.frame(city = c("Chicago", "New York", "Cincinatti", "Green Bay"), value = c(30, 50, 70, 95))
```

What's the path that it has to travel to go between my request and my receiving the data?

Is it going through external machines along that path?

Comment: You define the port inside the `r-script`  example: 

`require(plumber)
r <- plumb("lib/routes.R")
r$run(host="0.0.0.0",port=8000)`

Comment: Also you'll have to configure a Dockerfile installing all the dependencies and expose the port. If you want that another services have access to the `R` container you will have to link it inside a docker-compose.

Comment: Does anyone from plumber have access to the data at any point?

Comment: Anyone who knows the `endpoint` will have access, I think that the security part will have to handle the `r-script` or another backend service connected to the plumber container.

Comment: Excellent! It sounds like as long as I set up the docker instance and the endpoint securely, then I should be good to go. Can you tell me more about hiw it's traveling from my script to the docker instance and back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use `plumber` inside a docker container you will have to:

1. Make a Dockerfile with all the dependencies
2. Link inside docker-compose.yml

**Make the Dockerfile**

In this example you make an image with an `r-script` which route is `src/myscript.R`

```
FROM rocker/r-apt:bionic

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y -qq \
    libmariadb-client-lgpl-dev \
    r-cran-plumber \
    r-cran-reshape2 \
    r-cran-rmysql \
    r-cran-dplyr

COPY src src
RUN chmod 755 src

WORKDIR /src
RUN chmod 777 myscript.R

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["Rscript","myscript.R"]
```

In order to build the image with the Dockerfile run

```
docker image build -t my-plumber-image .
```

Note that the `.` at the end is the current work directory and `-t` stands for "tag"

**Link the image inside docker-compose**

```
version: '3'

services:
 mysql:
   image: mysql:5.7
   container_name: mysql-container
   environment:
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword
   ports:
     - "3306:3306"
 plumber:
   image: my-plumber-image
   build: my-plumber-image
   container_name: plumber-container
   ports:
     - "8000:8000"
   links:
     - mysql
```

After link the plumber to the other services you can have access through the port 8000 like any other POST/GET request. The `ip` is defined by the localmachine.

I recommend you to use postman for the request tests. Hope this can help you.

I didn't mention any example with `R` and `plumber` because in their website it's a really good short one.

**DB connection**

If you want to make a connection to a container use the following script:

```
DB_conn <- function(){
return(RMySQL::dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(),
          user = 'root', 
          password = 'mypassword',
          dbname = 'mydatabase',
          host = HOST, # Container name like "myservice_mysql_1" look in the logs
          port = PORT) # Default port 3306 
      )
}
```

Comment: Can I encrypt the tunnel between docker and the machine that runs the commands?

Comment: Haven't marked this complete because it's unclear whether plumbr has access to the data

Comment: In this example plumbr can access to MySQL container (specified in docker-compose.yml as `links`), so is just matter of DB configuration inside your R-script to retrieved data from the DB. If you want for example to grant access to a Mongo DB you'll have to link it inside the docker-compose.yml